# Programmatically Swap Staging Slot to Production Slot in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure-cloud-services

So unfortunately we haven't upgraded from Azure Cloud Service to App Service yet. But I'm wondering how to automatically swap the Staging slot to Production slot with a Release Task.

The automated Release sequence is something like: 1) deploy to staging, 2) manual confirmation to swap staging to production slot, and 3) (after manual confirmation received) swap slots and delete staging instance.

Comment: azure powershell?

Comment: Yeah that looks like it should work. Found this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Swap-the-Deployments-f588a811

Answer (score 1):

Yes so the script from here works to swap Staging and Production slots:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Swap-the-Deployments-f588a811

However, I had to set the Azure Powershell task to use an older version and classic resources.

Screen shots:

[image: Azure Powershell Task Version]

[image: Azure Powershell Version]

Comment: thanks for the share, this helped me solve the issue. Seems it might be needed due to AzModule and AzureRMModule's having their own PowerShell versions.